# ASP.NET Identity 2.1 change PK to int error

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity

I have changed the PK as described in http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/change-primary-key-for-users-in-aspnet-identity, however after I try to login, i get the following error. The login part is successful because "this" contains all the approperate data, however creating identity seems to fail

**The specified cast from a materialized 'System.String' type to the 'System.Int32' type is not valid.**

at the line

```
var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
```

of the method

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser, int> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Do you have ApplicationUserManager class which contains all the configurations and CreatePerOwinContext on Startup.cs?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem as well.. the only difference is that my error is during `AddToRole` or `AddToRoleAsync`.

> The specified cast from a materialized 'System.String' type to the 'System.Int32' type is not valid.

The offending line is at: `await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, model.RoleId);`

As it turns out, I need to change the key for table `AspNetRoles` as well... perhaps this picture makes it clearer..

[image]

Comment: Hope you could add more to the answer

Answer (score 3):

Clear your cookies. You probably have your application running before you changed PK and now is trying to log in using other 'key type' from the cookie.

Comment: This was my problem, had to clear cookies before it would work because of the old id value stored.  Another solution is to change the cookie name so you don't need to rely on all your users clearing their cookies when they see constant 500 errors.

Answer (score 0):

According to your source I assume that you are using ApplicationUserManager for managing all configurations. Use ApplicationUserManager instead of UserManager as follow. The reason GenerateUserIdentityAsync method used inside the owin startUp.

Use ApplicationUserManager instead of UserManager.

```
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUserManager manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
```

Hope this helps.