# After changing Identity PK to int: The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Int32' type to the 'System.String' type is not valid

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

ASP.NET website web forms application using Identity 2 (VS 2015). Generated site using standard template (all worked with Id of string), followed tutorial to change primary key of Users table to Int, and that is where problems began. Appears EF is retrieving the record at login, but unable to populate the ApplicationUser object.

Edited User table directly within SQL (Not code-first) if that matters. Tried overriding the Id (string) property of IdentityUser with Id (Int), however compiler balks at different return types. Suggestions?

```
Line 26:       **Dim user As ApplicationUser = manager.Find(Email.Text, Password.Text)**
Line 27:       If user IsNot Nothing Then
```

Error trace:

```
[InvalidOperationException: The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Int32' type to the 'System.String' type is not valid.]
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.ErrorHandlingValueReader`1.GetValue(DbDataReader reader, Int32 ordinal) +235
   lambda_method(Closure , Shaper ) +164
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper shaper) +181
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.<MoveNextAsync>d__4.MoveNext() +374
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.<FirstMoveNextAsync>d__0.MoveNext() +513
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.<FirstOrDefaultAsync>d__25`1.MoveNext() +350
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult() +59
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.<GetUserAggregateAsync>d__68.MoveNext() +346
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult() +59
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.<FindAsync>d__12.MoveNext() +272
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.AsyncHelper.RunSync(Func`1 func) +281
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManagerExtensions.Find(UserManager`2 manager, String userName, String password) +168
   Account_Login.LogIn(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Lauren\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\WebSites\Template\Account\Login.aspx.vb:26
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +109
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +108
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +31
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3449
```

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.57.0

Comment: I am having this problem during `UserManager.AddRole(userId, roleId)`. Any clue how to solve this?

Comment: I found the answer, check out this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32584881/193634